# Single Cell Calculation of the Average Count of Unique Words

Tags: excel, count, average

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
Apple
Banana
Banana
Carrot
Pear
Pear
Pear
Pear
Pear
```

I'd like to use a formula to find out on average how many times an item appears in the list. At the moment, I create another table listing each item just once and then use `COUNTIF` to find the number of times each item appears:

```
Apple  1
Banana 2
Carrot 1
Pear   5
```

In another cell, I then average these numbers to reach a figure of 2.25.

Is there a way to simplify this and calculate it using an (array?) formula in a single cell?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not require an array formula:

```
=COUNTA(A1:A9)/SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A9, A1:A9))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

It turns out that the average of the unique counts is actually:

***=(total count of items) / (count of uniques)***

**EDIT#2:**

To cover the entire column and exclude blanks, use the *Array Formula*:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)/SUM(IF(A:A<>"",1/COUNTIF(A:A,A:A ), 0))
```

*Array Formulas* must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

This is **painfully slow** to calculate, so I recommend restricting the cells in column **A** to something reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, although would you mind intuitively explaining why this works and how it calculates it?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One more question, if I may: how do I amend the formula to work when the data range isn't fixed? So at times the data will be in A1:A9, whilst at others it could extend down to A500 etc. The above formula doesn't seem to work when I include a large number of blank cells, and I'd like to avoid amending the formula each time dependant on the data range.